# Android Volley NetworkImageView not working with SOME images

Tags: android, http, networking, android-volley

I am using Volley's NetworkImageView by calling setImageUrl:

```
mANetworkImageView.setImageUrl(url, getImageLoader());
```

It has always been working great, until I used this image link, which it won't open, I only get `com.android.volley.ServerError`

Link with ERROR: http://sto-static.s3.amazonaws.com/images/avatars/149014.jpg
(if I open it in my phone's browser, it opens)

Example of working link: http://c-sf.smule.com/s24/arr/e7/c9/8fea1cf7-9500-4102-9c8c-85fc98b31a21.jpg

What could be the differences between the two links that may cause this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://sto-static.s3.amazonaws.com/images/avatars/149014.jpg
```

This is download link. Use your original data link.

Comment: @MarceloLiKoga Please read the tutorial - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: I changed the MIME type to image/jpeg, but I still get error 400. Any other ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. I was using wrong `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` as the request body content type.

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that your first link has the wrong MIME type. It is reported as `application/octet-stream`, not `image/jpeg`.